# Рывки при трансляции mpeg с помощью Motion

Tags: debian, rtsp, motion, видеонаблюдение

Установил на сервере Motion (на сервере debian). Он читает видео с камеры по rtsp. Все работает хорошо, кроме трансляции потока: он идет рывками. то есть, это не плавное видео, а как бы слайд-шоу.

Как это можно обойти? Может кто сталкивался с подобным?